# How to make fill Rectangle without color in ActionScript 3.0 to see behind it

Tags: actionscript-3

I just started working on as3. I want to create a `Rectangle` but without color fill, so I can see what is behind it on stage. I love to draw on that `Rectangle`, but it never works without color fill.

```
var Canvas_sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(Canvas_sp);

//here i love  Rectangle be without collor fill  not whit(FFFFFF)e color
//i love see what behind the Rectangle and draw over it 

Canvas_sp.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
Canvas_sp.graphics.drawRect(0,0,550,400);
```

thx for all

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a fill, don't begin one.

Omit this line:

```
Canvas_sp.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal you want, you need to set the alpha parameter to 0, and maybe, to draw just a border of a Rectangle. You can see an example here: [example](http://wonderfl.net/c/2jTy)

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
Canvas_sp.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 0);
Canvas_sp.graphics.lineStyle(0x000000, 0.1);
Canvas_sp.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
Canvas_sp.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: thx alot to all  its really work  i can now draw on Rectangle and see what behind it :)  from the last code  im so happy for support  thx again